# How I can create a table with two primary keys in T-sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

What is the problem in this code?

```
CREATE TABLE pharmacy_night
(
    [Id_day] INT NOT NULL ,
    [Id_pharmacy] INT,
    constraint pk_pharmacy_night primary key (Id_day, Id_pharmacy),
    constraint fk_pharmacy_night_days foreign key (Id_day) references days(Id_day),
    constraint fk_pharmacy_night_pharmacy foreign key (Id_pharmacy) references pharmacy (Id_pharmacy)


)
```

Comment: You can only have one primary key,  but you can have composite primary key.

Comment: yes i mean composite primary key

Comment: Can u add more, why do you need two primary key in one table? If both are important then split them into two tables or use composite key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for composite key

```
create table abc (
  ID int,
  number int,
  constraint PK_abc primary key (ID, number)
);
```

And try this for Primary key

```
create table abc
(
ID int primary key,
number int
)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, when i try to update i receive errors

Comment: What error? Explain your business case please...

Comment: Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.  
Please correct the following errors and try again.


SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.abc.
SQL71501 :: Primary Key: [dbo].[PK_abc] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[abc].
SQL71501 :: Primary Key: [dbo].[PK_abc] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[abc].
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.abc.number.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.abc.ID.

Comment: This error is not helping other than getting that error is coming form some server side code. What is your insert or update query with data please?

Check this [SQL FIlddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1061a/1)

Comment: what do you mean in insert query?just i want to create a table with a composite key

Comment: it'is ok.. I solve the problem..

Comment: Okay, so why don't you drop the existing table if any with the same name and references.. Could you fire a select * from <YourTableName> to check if that exist.. or check if any reference exist with that name..